# Apache 2.4 exact redirection matching strings

Tags: redirect, query-string, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have a URL :
https://www.example.com/login/login.cgi?user=option

Want to exactly match login.cgi

If user hits https://www.example.com/login/login.cgi need to redirect to external site say [www.redirect.com](http://www.redirect.com)

If anyone hits https://www.example.com/login/login.cgi?user=option it should not cause any redirection.

I tried various option of query string and as well Rewrite rules seems to not work.

I tried using :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^login.cgi$
RewriteRule ^login/$   https://www.redirect.com? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?login/login\.cgi$ https://example.com [R,L]
```

This will redirect `yoursite.com/login/login.cgi` to `example.com` .

The condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` matches `empty querystring` meaning that when the    the URI is `/login/login.cgi` without any querystring the `Rewriterule`  will be applied.

The `/?` in the beginning of RewriteRule pattern makes it possible to use the rule in both contexts `server.config` or in `htaccess`.

Comment: @vins.vini your welcome! Glad I could be of help. Cheers :)

Comment: @AmitVerma, hey Amit bro, greetings!! I am sorry if I am disturbing you here, could you please do take a look to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455070/5866580 once if this looks good to you :) Thank you for your as always guidance cheers :)